# Can't assign to property defined as writable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have this snippet, but can't figure why it throws an error when trying to assign a value to a property defined as writable:

```
function Constructor()
{
    Object.seal(this);
}

Object.defineProperties(Constructor.prototype,
{
  field: {value: null, writable: true}
});


var instance = new Constructor();

instance.field = 'why this doesn\'t work??';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignments to object properties are **always** assignments to local "own" properties of the object itself. The fact that there's a like-named property on the prototype doesn't matter. Your instance is a sealed object, so you can't write to it.

If you were to call

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(instance).field = "this works";
```

you'd be OK.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the exact expected behavior.  Checking the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal

```
Sealing an object prevents new properties from being added and marks all existing properties as non-configurable. This has the effect of making the set of properties on the object fixed and immutable
```

The important bit being "making the set properties on the object fixed and immutable"